# HashMap in OpenCL?

Tags: hashmap, opencl

Is it possible to create a simple HashMap in OpenCL? E.g. one where all keys have type `long` and all values type `int`, and that never has to be modified (i.e. is passed read-only to the kernel).

Construction of the HashMap can take time (is it done once on the CPU and never has to be modified again), but read-access will be frequent, so `get(long key, *hashmap H)` should be cheap.

Are there any known implementations for this in OpenCL? I failed to find them. In case I'd have to write one from scratch, which HashMap implementation would be most suitable for this use?

Comment: Maybe search for CUDA, isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533102/cuda-implementing-device-hash-map) helpfull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a simple hash table implementation using [open addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing) could fulfill your requirements here:

- By its nature it is stored on a single buffer, and thus trivial to transfer to the kernels.
- It's then easy to write the getter logic in the kernel, especially when you don't need any synchronization (read-only).

So, pass a buffer of `long2` or a buffer of `struct { long key; int val; }`, when the first item is the key and the second the value, and also pass the buffer size; now write a regular open-address getter.