# Hashmap data structure in CUDA

Tags: data-structures, cuda, gpu

I am looking for a high performance data structure on GPU (preferably over CUDA). The CUDPP is something cool but it does not satisfy my requirements because I want my key to be fixed size int array. I need to query 10k+ queries per second over a KEY-VALUE store of size 1M+. Is there any library already providing such type of functionality. I tried alternates on CPU but they are not that good for the purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CUDA - Implementing Device Hash Map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533102/cuda-implementing-device-hash-map)

Comment: Please provide some more details about your application and the type of queries required. It should be very easy to do 10k+ lookups or inserts on a few MB sized hash on the CPU alone. http://incise.org/hash-table-benchmarks.html lists millions of queries per second for  unordered_map on CPU alone.

Comment: @sgarizvi not at all, thats why i explicitly mentioned CUDPP

Comment: @JanLucas  10k+ lookup is easy if we are looking for a primitive data type. But here in my use case, I need to encode an object as string or an array of ints and make it the key of the container. In my use case, there is no concept of ordering , which makes the problem worse.

Comment: @hellboy: Maybe the data structure itself is not the issue, but the cost of serializing and hashing the objects. How many bytes do you have per key on average?

Comment: @JanLucas key size is 10 byte on average. Yeah, you are right, its the serializing thing, I will use this container in a multi-threaded application and hence I want it to be threadsafe. In that case c++ stl maps with stl array as the data structure are not good if we consider the threadsafety criteria, thats why I wanted to migrate to GPU

Comment: Moving to the GPU will not automatically get you thread-safety, in many case it will even be harder to be thread safe. ~10 byte keys should not be an issue. These keys are still small. unordered_map is safe for concurrent lookups, but needs locks if you want to do parallel inserts. If you want to do concurrent inserts, you can use concurrent_hash_map from Intel's thread building blocks. Unfortunately you do not provide a lot of information about your application but at the moment it does not sound like your application would benefit from moving to CUDA.

Comment: @JanLucas , hey sorry I just now noticed a mistake I made, the no. of keys is 100M+ . I am using this data structure for ant-colony optimization to store the values of pheromones. For obvious reasons I want it to be fast. Key size is ~10-15 bytes because there is no ordering on the value of keys and hence I cannot have a mapping to integer. I want concurrent lookups and update. I made a prototype of the data structure over the last week and it works concurrently, but even now open to using an existing library because my DS is not completely tested.

Comment: BTW, `warpcore` is a framework for creating high-throughput, purpose-built hashing data structures on CUDA-accelerators. Hashing at the speed of light on modern CUDA-accelerators. You can find it here:

https://github.com/sleeepyjack/warpcore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it, though I have heard about a hashmap extension for CUDA Thrust. Present here:

Cuda-thrust-extensions [library](http://code.google.com/p/cuda-thrust-extensions/)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there anything better option available. Sorry for sounding naive but I am a newbie to GPU computing.